# Storing strings in an array

Tags: c, recursion

The code given below prints all the possible combination of a given string. It produces strings recursively . Now i want to store each combination in an array using an array of pointer to each string . How do i initialize the pointer so that it points to string. 
The code is :-

```
Input ABC
Output 

ABC in b[0]
ACB in b[1]
BAC 
BCA
CAB 
CBA
```

and so on .

thanks :)

```
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
  int k=0;
  char *b[100];
   int j;
   if (i == n)
     {
      // *b[k]=a;
     printf("%s\n", a);
      i++;
     }
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how many combinations there are up front? Do you want the array to be pre-allocated or do you want it dynamically allocated? Do you know the difference?

Comment: Yes there will be n! combination of the string .

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in pointing elements of `b` to `a`, since is `a` variable string (that is, it keeps changing). Possible output of such code would be that all elements of `b` would be last permutation of the string `a`.

You need dynamic allocation of string each time you find a new permutation.
That you can do manually using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc). Or can use [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) to create duplicate strings for you (Remember to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) them at the end ofcourse).

```
/*Sample Code*/

if (i == n)
{
  b[k] = strdup(a);
  ...
}
```

Remember, that you also need to pass `k` as the argument to the function `permute()`, since `k` is an automatic variable, newly created with value = `0`, each time function `permute()` is called. There are other possibilities, make `k` `global` or `static` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically allocate an array that would hold individual char arrays (or C strings) representing each permutation. One of the things that would make this code generic is to find the value of total_permutations in the main() for a given string with strlen N, which would actually be factorial(N). Here:

```
void swap(char* A, char* B) {
    char t;
    t = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = t;
}

int permute(char **arr_of_chars, int count, char *a, int i, int n)
{
    int k=0;
    char *b[100];
    int j;
    if (i == n) {
        // *b[k]=a;
        printf("%s\n", a);
        memcpy(arr_of_chars[count], a, strlen(a));
        count++;
        i++;
    } else {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
        swap((a+i), (a+j));
        count = permute(arr_of_chars, count, a, i+1, n);
        swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "";
    char **arr_of_str = NULL;
    int len_str = strlen(str);
    int i = len_str;
    int total_permutations = 1;

    while (i > 0) { /* Get all the combinations */
        total_permutations *= i;
        i--;
    }

    arr_of_str = (char **) malloc(total_permutations * sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0; i <total_permutations; i++) {
        arr_of_str[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * len_str);
    }

    permute(arr_of_str, 0, str, 0, (len_str-1));

    for (i=0; i <total_permutations; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", arr_of_str[i]);
        free(arr_of_str[i]);
    }
    free(arr_of_str);
}
```